# Regular language union non-regular language

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I have the following languages:

$ L_1 = (P \cup \{b\})^*$

$P = \{a^p | p = prime\}$ for example $ \{aa, aaa, aaaaa\} $

I am told that $L_1$ is regular and thus I should be able to create a finite automata for it, correct? But since $P$ cannot possibly be regular how can I draw this $union$ ?

This is what I have so far:
[image: (P | {b})]
The $\{b\}$ part is fairly straight forward, but I am stuck on how to represent $P$

For example a valid string could be $\epsilon$, $bb$ or $aab$ but since I cannot keep track on how many a's we have gone trough so far how could I possible make a finite automata out of it? or would $aab$ be a invalid string and the regular expression of the whole thing would simply be $b^*$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given

$$L = (P \cup \{b\})^*, \quad P = \{a^p \mid p \text{ is prime}\}$$

you want to show that $L$ is regular.

**Hint:**

- Set $P' = \{aa, aaa\} \subseteq P$ and observe that $L' = \big(\{aa, aaa, b\}\big)^* \subseteq L$.
- Can you give a more direct definition of $L'$?

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: It helps but I am still confused :) Is however I try to draw a DFA for primes using combinations $a^2$ and $a^3$ (since every prime can be described with a combination of $2n+3m$) I can allways sneak in a non-prime to get to acceptance since I can allso easily describe $a^4$ the same way.

Comment: @darrrrUC Ok, let me check one thing – please answer these two questions: does or does not $a^4 \in L'$, does or does not $a^4 \in L$?

Comment: $a^4$ is in neither, but could I not create it with a string such as $a^2$ $a^2$ Or is that just an invalid string since it adds to a $a^4$? Thank you for your patience :)

Comment: What i ment is that $a^5$ is in $L$ and that is $a^2 + a^3$ ?

Comment: @darrrrUC Check out the examples section: [Kleene star](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star).

Comment: Yes and since we apply the kleene star to the set  $\{aa,aaa\}^*$ we get ${\epsilon, aa, aaa, aaaa, aaaaa, aaaaaa, ...}$ and this is what I cant grasp my head on how to work around since we get $aaaa$ that is not a prime :/ Im probably stuck in my way of thinking atm :/

Comment: @darrrrUC You expanded $\{aa,aaa\}^*$ correctly. Could you do this for $\{aa,aaa,b\}^*$?

Comment: $ \epsilon, aa, aaa, b, aab, aaab, bb, aaaa, aaaaaa, ...$ ? :)

Comment: @darrrrUC Great. Now, would be there any differences between $\{aa,aaa,b\}^*$ and $\{aa,aaa,a^5,a^7,a^{11},b\}^*$ and $(P \cup \{b\})^*$?

Comment: It should not be, since every prime can be described with a combination of $aa$ and $aaa$

Comment: @darrrrUC Cool, then if these languages are the same, why don't you just construct an automata for $\{aa, aaa, b\}^*$ instead of $(P \cup \{b\})^*$?

Comment: But if I allow a transition for $aa$ -> $aa$ we could go to 4? Lets say I wish to try for $"aaaaaaa"$ (7). I would go $aa$ -> $aa$ -> $aaa$ -> acceptance in my automata. Now lets say I wish to try for $aa$ i go from $aa$ -> acceptance. Could I by this logic not now try for $aaaa$ (not a prime) and go $aa$ -> $aa$ -> acceptance. Thus my finite automata accept strings that are not prime.

Comment: So all strings accepted by the automata should be prime and/or b? But if we have $\{aa, aaa, b\}^*$ I can create the strings $aaaa, aaaaaa$ etc.

Comment: @darrrrUC That's the point every answer here tries to state: the final language doesn't care for prime numbers, and the corresponding automata doesn't need to recognize them in any way (and thus it is possible for it to be regular). You could say that the property of being prime in $P$ is a kind of red herring.

Comment: Oh, ok, I tought no non-primes were allowed to slip trough to the final state. I thank you a million for your patience in this long thread, know that I truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Try first to figure what $P^*$ means - Some concatenation of words in prime length. Now note that for every $n \geq 2$ we can present him as $n = {p_1}^{a_1} \cdot ... \cdot {p_k}^{a_k}$ so for every $n \geq 2$ you can get that $a^n$ is in $P^*$.

Now we get that $L_1$ is actually every word that doesnt have lone $a$'s inside her - which is easy to identify using automata - whenever you get an $a$ that starts an $a$-sequence you going to a reject state, unless you get another $a$ right away.

Comment: In order to write $a^n$ as a concatenation of words of the form $a^p$ with $p$ prime, you need to express $n$ as a *sum* of primes, not a product. This is possible for $n \geq 2$ since then $n$ is a sum of $2$'s and possibly a $3$.

Comment: multiplication and power are actually a lot of additions, so it doesnt matter. However, I do agree that what you suggested would be more simple to understand.